# PHP - Sending a multi-dimensional array and parsing to pass to function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently building an MVC-ish structure on our project. My objective is to create panels with a function call. However, I'm currently stuck on how to pass a call to a function, that requires two parameters, within a `foreach` loop.

Function Call (not working)

```
        $display_panel_create->get_display_create_panel($size=6, $title='Guest',
          $field=['join_two_fields' => ['field1' => 'first_name','field2' => 'last_name'], 'email', 'phone',
              'company','address', 'comments'], $action='Create', $type='success');
```

The receiving method is:

```
function get_display_create_panel($size, $title, $field, $action, $type){

  $panel = '';

  $panel .= $this->panel_size($size);
  $panel .= $this->panel_header($title, $action, $type);
  $panel .= $this->panel_form($action, $title);
  $panel .= $this->panel_body($field);
  $panel .= $this->button($type);
  $panel .= $this->panel_footer();

return $panel;

}
```

As we create new "parts", the body call is a `foreach` loop that does the following:

protected function panel_body($field){

```
$body = '';


foreach ($field as $item){

  if (is_array($item)){

    foreach ($item as $k => $v){

      if ($k == 'join_two_fields'){

        $body .= $this->$k($field1 = $v['field1'], $field2=$v['field2']);
        unset ($item[$k]);

      } else { $body .= $this->$k($v); }

    }

  } else { $body .= $this->$item(); }
}

return $body;
}
```

However, a panel is not being created. I tried using test.php file to make sure my looping is correct, and I realized that my issue is that during the initial loop, i'm not sending both variables for `$field1` and `$field2`.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant solution?

--------- test.php code --------

```
$array = [$size=6, $title='Guest',
          $field=[
            'join_two_fields' =>
              ['field1' => 'first_name','field2' => 'last_name'],
            'email', 'phone', 'company','address', 'comments'],
          $action='Create', $type='success'
         ];

foreach ($array as $item){

  if (is_array($item)){

    foreach ($item as $k => $v){

      if ($k == 'join_two_fields'){
        echo $v['field1'] . '<br>';
        echo $v['field2'] . '<br>';

      }
      else { echo $v . '<br>'; }

    }

  } else { echo $item . '<br>'; }
}
```

--------test.php output---------

6
Guest
first_name
last_name
e
e
phone
company
address
comments
Create
success

Comment: Im confused about this line `$body .= $this->$k($field1 = $v['field1'], $field2=$v['field2']);` what is the `$this->$k()` suppose to do? do you have a method named `join_two_fields()` ?

Comment: You're referencing $this->$k but are looping using $k. If you put error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top of your PHP file you'd see a warning about a reference to an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by a _"panel"_? What is your main output supposed to be?

Comment: @CodeGodie - yes, there is a method `join_two_fields` that joins the two fields and outputs a line in a panel.

Comment: @Kalkran - I updated the question to show the loop inside my test.php and output to show that it's looping somewhat correctly, and `$k` is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you are iterating. Lets break it down:

you first run this:

```
foreach ($field as $item) {
```

This will set your `$item` as all the array's values such as this mocukup:

```
"join_two_fields" => $item,
0 => $item,
1 => $item,
2 => $item,
3 => $item,
4 => $item
```

Then you check if `$item` is an array , and if it is you loop through `$item` with another `foreach' inside`:

```
foreach ($field as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            foreach ($item as $k => $v) {
```

which then `$item` would be something like this:

```
     $k => $v

     OR

    'field1' => 'first_name' 
    'field2' => 'last_name'
```

so far so good, ts working, here comes the problem. After your iterations, you have your condition `if ($k == 'join_two_fields') {` which checks if the current key equals `"join_two_fields"`, well **this will never happen** . What you mean to check here is the original key of your first iteration, not the key in the second iteration.

To fix this, redo your iteration in this manner, remove your second `foreach` as you do not need to iterate over the fields:

```
    foreach ($field as $field_key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            if ($field_key == 'join_two_fields') {
                $body .= $this->$field_key($field1 = $item['field1'], $field2 = $item['field2']);
            } else {
                $body .= $this->$field_key($item);
            }
        } else {
            $body .= $this->$item();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you sir. Technically, this approach doesn't work however. The logic is sound, but with the `foreach` loop, once its inside the third spin and hitting `join_two_fields`, you can't pull variables. I tested via `echo` commands, as well as code. I'll update my question later on once this is solved and display your code with `echo`, in case it helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that I noticed, like the one I mentioned in my comment above, however the biggest issue I notice is the way you are naming your parameters. If Im not mistaken, this does not match what you are supposed to be receiving in your function.

This is what I mean:

You currently pass parameters to the `get_display_create_panel` method this way:

```
$display_panel_create->get_display_create_panel(
      $size=6, 
      $title='Guest', 
      $action='Create', 
      $type='success', 
      $field=['email', 'phone', 'company','address', 'comments',                                  
              'join_two_fields' => [
                  'field1' => 'first_name',
                  'field2' => 'last_name'], 
              ]
);
```

This means that `get_display_create_panel()` should expect something like:

```
get_display_create_panel($size, $title, $action, $type, $field)
```

But you have it like this:

```
get_display_create_panel($size, $title, $field, $action, $type)
```

Which is inconsistent as it does not match. Make those match and that should fix your main issue.

Comment: I actually re-formated the call to display better in SO, otherwise it was all over the place. My call matches the `method` parameters, sir. I updated the question with the proper call to avoid confusion, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

you should change `if ($k == 'join_two_fields')` to `if ($k === 'join_two_fields')`
because `$k == 'join_two_fields'` is **true** when `$k= 0`

so test.php will work as below

```js
$array = [$size=6, $title='Guest',
          $field=[
            'join_two_fields' =>
              ['field1' => 'first_name','field2' => 'last_name'],
            'email', 'phone', 'company','address', 'comments'],
          $action='Create', $type='success'
         ];

foreach ($array as $item){

  if (is_array($item)){

    foreach ($item as $k => $v){

      if ($k === 'join_two_fields'){
        echo $v['field1'] . '<br>';
        echo $v['field2'] . '<br>';

      }
      else { echo $v . '<br>'; }

    }

  } else { echo $item . '<br>'; }
}
```